# Hash Mismatch from us.archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: apt, security, mirrors

```
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 firefox amd64 98.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 [57.7 MB]                                                       Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 firefox amd64 98.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:                                                                 - SHA512:b2f868233d78980fcbecf7e7af54d4816f195b0d09272dce0b752f1ee59b246e2c9739e3e723f63e8358929cbc29bc4e2bccd351694f0aa9aaefda342986448b                                       - SHA256:eea07cd221519909ba017d2e88ed7e2b91c2b1d5835a45bb23c742733f1edc1d
   - SHA1:684b4051ad90e59e66f9b13b948c2ae06b33e064 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:9ef4179fc2f0d9f07e51b6d8c0698c99 [weak]                                        - Filesize:57700268 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:                                                                 - SHA512:2ac52fe8934c3c6a2d461fb0965dffcc5a43ec4e9e83399c549f3ea4b1878987aaf9de7b96c765712e0a7ecc5394a36fcc8e0346b8a3707775833c7cd68e0fde
   - SHA256:f82f3b3d98128e1e5371c5a5bb6001e275329df7a0493cbbb5011c81f891f8bb               - SHA1:832c06086976ce4e1988fa0e40518e06b24c1bca [weak]                                  - MD5Sum:a50f21cb8c53a75d731501fc8e6dffb1 [weak]
   - Filesize:57700268 [weak]                                                             Last modification reported: Thu, 24 Mar 2022 15:21:10 +0000                           Fetched 57.7 MB in 4s (15.7 MB/s)                                                       E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox_98.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA512:b2f868233d78980fcbecf7e7af54d4816f195b0d09272dce0b752f1ee59b246e2c9739e3e723f63e8358929cbc29bc4e2bccd351694f0aa9aaefda342986448b                                       - SHA256:eea07cd221519909ba017d2e88ed7e2b91c2b1d5835a45bb23c742733f1edc1d               - SHA1:684b4051ad90e59e66f9b13b948c2ae06b33e064 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:9ef4179fc2f0d9f07e51b6d8c0698c99 [weak]                                        - Filesize:57700268 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:                                                                 - SHA512:2ac52fe8934c3c6a2d461fb0965dffcc5a43ec4e9e83399c549f3ea4b1878987aaf9de7b96c765712e0a7ecc5394a36fcc8e0346b8a3707775833c7cd68e0fde                                       - SHA256:f82f3b3d98128e1e5371c5a5bb6001e275329df7a0493cbbb5011c81f891f8bb
    - SHA1:832c06086976ce4e1988fa0e40518e06b24c1bca [weak]
    - MD5Sum:a50f21cb8c53a75d731501fc8e6dffb1 [weak]
    - Filesize:57700268 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Thu, 24 Mar 2022 15:21:10 +0000
```

Comment: Mirror sync? I have seen this question before and it was mirror sync

Comment: Hello. What is the actual question?